# how to adjust ssl iframe dynamic height

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have requirement ,showing  div as popup in my site, i load the div with iframe,the iframe has https content but the div is in http content , i need adjust the iframe height but my script failed here due to the https content not able to call out side script which is increases the ifram width .It says permission denied error message. please help any one

Comment: Detail less question. Can't understand anything out of it

Answer (score 0):

The outlying page is http and the inner iframe is https: Please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/sm6dX/